# JNativeHook multiple responses from the same action (mouse click, key type & mouse scroll)

Tags: java, multithreading, hook, system-calls

I'm using JNativeHook to retrieve information on how active a user is, but I am having an issue where I will get multiple responses from a single action but it's not consistent. It changes between 1, 2 or 3 responses but never more than 3 and I will have to run and exit the program multiple times in order to get the different results. It can seem to work for an entire day before I find the issue has occurred again.

I have also had the problem where I have to restart my computer in order to get some sort of response from an action.

An example print out from the program:

Mouse Pressed: 1 
Mouse Pressed: 1
Mouse Pressed: 1
Mouse Released: 1
Mouse Clicked: 3
Mouse Released: 1
Mouse Clicked: 3
Mouse Released: 1
Mouse Clicked: 3

I am using 3 classes, one for each: mouse listener, keyboard listener and a mouse wheel listener. I create a thread of each of these to have them run concurrently.

There are 4 main classes that deal with code that has the issue:

1. [Class that contains the threads](https://github.com/joedawtry/VocabTool/blob/master/src/controller/InterruptionDecision.java)
2. [Keyboard listener](https://github.com/joedawtry/VocabTool/blob/master/src/model/KeyboardListener.java)
3. [Mouse Listener](https://github.com/joedawtry/VocabTool/blob/master/src/model/MouseListener.java)
4. [Mouse Wheel Listener.](https://github.com/joedawtry/VocabTool/blob/master/src/model/MouseWheelListener.java)

(There was a lot of code that I was going post which almost made the post unreadable so I hope it's okay to do it like this?)

I am new to using JNativeHook and I'm not sure if it is maybe creating multiple objects of the same global listener or a concurrency issue.

Comment: If you are still experiencing the same sort of issue, please report a bug.  There was a few thread safety issues that may have caused that behavior that have been addressed in 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, please if you find any bug with JnativeHook report it at [there](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/issues/list), there is any related thing with SOF.

**UPDATE** now on 2016 the lib moved to [Github](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook)